# Enterprise library 5.0 examples?

Tags: c#, asp.net, enterprise-library

I am starting EL 5.0 for Exception Handling and Logging. I want write a fair business logic for these EL components. If you guys have any good examples or blogs or links to write these. Please share with me.

Comment: You can find comprehensive code samples for Enterprise Library 5.0 here: http://entlib.codeplex.com/releases/view/46741. Look under *Other Available Downloads*

Comment: I have that. Looking for some more samples

Comment: Requests for lists of outside resources are generally off-topic everywhere in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?